How To Use MUI Dashboard with Router to have Main Content Change Routing
I'm sure this is an easy 'thing' to do, but there's very little explanation on how a react-router or MUI Router even works, so I'm getting lost and confused and I'd like to see if there's a better, clearer answer here.
I've got a site with an MUI Dashboard with a left nav, some left nav items, and list views to show some stuff.  I know how to add to the current Router on my AppProvider component.  Anything in that DashboardLayout that sends back a route (to one of my lists) loads up the List component that I have created.
What I'm wondering is: how do I get any of my list components to then drill down to a detail of whatever I click on.  For example, if my Dashboard has three components (List1, List2, and List3) and I click on List2, it loads up List2 in the main content portion of the DashboardLayout.  When I click on a row in List2, I want the main content to then 'route' to my List2Detail component to show that component's detail information in the main content.


//Dashboard.tsx
import React, { useState, useMemo } from "react";

import AccessAlarmIcon from "@mui/icons-material/AccessAlarm";
import AssignmentIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Assignment";
import HomeIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Home";
import ReportIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Report";

import {
  AppProvider,
  DashboardLayout,
  Navigation,
  Router,
} from "@toolpad/core";

import HomeView from "./HomeView";
import JobList from "./JobList";
import ScheduleList from "./ScheduleList";
import AuditLogList from "./AuditLogList";
import { WhedaLightTheme } from "../themes/WhedaLightTheme";
import JobDetail from "./JobDetail";

const navigation: Navigation = [
  {
    kind: "header",
    title: "Actions",
  },
  {
    segment: "home",
    title: "Home View",
    icon: <HomeIcon />,
  },
  {
    segment: "jobList",
    title: "Jobs",
    icon: <AssignmentIcon />,
  },
  {
    segment: "scheduleList",
    title: "Schedules",
    icon: <AccessAlarmIcon />,
  },
  {
    segment: "auditLogList",
    title: "Audit Log",
    icon: <ReportIcon />,
  },
];

interface DashboardProps {
  window?: () => Window;
}

const Dashboard = (props: DashboardProps) => {
  const { window } = props;

  const [pathname, setPathname] = useState("/home");
  const [mainContent, setMainContent] = useState<JSX.Element>(<div />);

  const router = useMemo<Router>(() => {
    switch (pathname) {
      case "/home":
        setMainContent(<HomeView />);
        break;
      case "/jobList":
        setMainContent(<JobList />);
        break;
      case "/scheduleList":
        setMainContent(<ScheduleList />);
        break;
      case "/auditLogList":
        setMainContent(<AuditLogList />);
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }

    return {
      pathname,
      searchParams: new URLSearchParams(),
      navigate: (path) => setPathname(String(path)),
    };
  }, [pathname]);

  return (
    <AppProvider
      navigation={navigation}
      branding={{
        logo: <img src={"src/assets/whedaLogo.svg"} alt="WHEDA Logo" />,
        title: "WHEDA Automation Scheduler",
      }}
      router={router}
      theme={WhedaLightTheme}
      window={window}
    >
      <DashboardLayout>{mainContent}</DashboardLayout>
    </AppProvider>
  );
};

export default Dashboard;





// JobList.tsx
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
import { DataGrid, GridColDef, GridEventListener } from "@mui/x-data-grid";

import Job from "../models/Job";

const columns: GridColDef[] = [
  {
    field: "name",
    headerName: "Name",
    width: 300,
  },
  {
    field: "uri",
    headerName: "Target URI",
    width: 600,
  },
  {
    field: "requestType",
    headerName: "Request Type",
    width: 120,
  },
  {
    field: "params",
    headerName: "Optional Params",
    width: 300,
  },
];

const JobList = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState<Job[]>([]);
  const [selectedRows, setSelectedRows] = useState([]);
  const [selectedJobID, setSelectedJobID] = useState<string | null>(null);
  const [detailOpen, setDetailOpen] = useState<boolean>(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    getJobList();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (selectedJobID != null) {
      handleOpen();
    }
  }, [selectedJobID]);

  const handleOpen = () => setDetailOpen(true);
  const handleClose = () => setDetailOpen(false);

  const getJobList = async () => {
    const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5022/Job/GetAll");
    setData(await response.json());
  };

  const handleJobSelected: GridEventListener<"rowClick"> = (params) => {
    //!! THIS IS WHERE I WANT THE ROUTER TO SHOW MY NEW JobDetail COMPONENT BASED ON MY SELECTED ROW
  };

  return (
    <Box
      sx={{
        py: 4,
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "column",
        alignItems: "center",
        textAlign: "center",
      }}
    >
      <Typography>Current Jobs</Typography>
      <DataGrid
        rows={data}
        columns={columns}
        initialState={{
          pagination: {
            paginationModel: {
              pageSize: 5,
            },
          },
        }}
        pageSizeOptions={[5, 10, 25]}
        onRowClick={handleJobSelected}
      />
    </Box>
  );
};

export default JobList;





// JobDetail.tsx
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import Modal from "@mui/material/Modal";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";

import Job from "../models/Job";

const modalStyle = {
  position: "absolute",
  top: "50%",
  left: "50%",
  transform: "translate(-50%, -50%)",
  width: 400,
  bgcolor: "background.paper",
  border: "2px solid #000",
  boxShadow: 24,
  p: 4,
};

interface JobDetailProps {
  open: boolean;
  currentJobId: string | null;
  handleClose: () => void;
}

const JobDetail = (props: JobDetailProps) => {
  const { open, currentJobId, handleClose } = props;

  const [jobID, setJobID] = useState<string | null>(null);
  const [job, setJob] = useState<Job | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (open) {
      setJobID(currentJobId);
    }
  }, [props]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getJobDetails();
  }, [jobID]);

  const getJobDetails = async () => {
    if (jobID != null) {
      const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5022/Job/" + jobID);
      setJob(await response.json());
    }
  };

  return (
    <Modal open={open} onClose={handleClose}>
      <Box sx={modalStyle}>
        <Typography>Job Details</Typography>
        <br />
        <Typography>ID: {job?.id}</Typography>
        <br />
        <Typography>Name: {job?.name}</Typography>
        <br />
        <Typography>Target URI: {job?.uri}</Typography>
        <br />
        <Typography>Request Type: {job?.requestType}</Typography>
        <br />
        <Typography>Optional Params: {job?.params}</Typography>
        <br />
      </Box>
    </Modal>
  );
};

export default JobDetail;



